# How to run virtual environment in python

Tags: python, python-venv

Following docs on [creating virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html), I created a virtual environment using,

`python3 -m venv ./venv`

traversing the `./venv` directory lists the virtual environment related files.

```
bin
include
lib
pyvenv.cfg
```

Now, how do I run my virtual environment ? Also, where are my actual packages / links to actual packages are stored ?

Comment: This question appears to ask StackOverflow to read out the documentation. Instead of the technical documentation, perhaps examine a guide: https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/

Comment: Read further down in that documentation to the part where it says *"Once a virtual environment has been created, it can be “activated”…"*…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to activate the environment. To do that run the following command

`source bin/activate`.

[Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)

Comment: Or on Windows, `bin\activate.bat`